# Cant add new Report Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, report, reportviewer

Here how its suppose to look

[image]

How it looks in my VS

[image]

I installed the Nuget packets:

Microsoft.Report.Viewer / v11.0.0

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms / v150.1400.0

Also installed the RDLC Designer from Extensions and Updates

Comment: Have you searched in search box ? [link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/images/2017/Dealing-with-New-Files-in-Visual-Studio-Projects/WrongFocus.png)

Comment: Search box shows no results

Comment: @Benedikt Treml, you can refer to the link [How to add reportviewer control in visual studio 2017 vb .net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f72d92a1-e7f8-4212-a0d7-8fa7c898658d/how-to-add-reportviewer-control-in-visual-studio-2017-vb-net?forum=winformsdesigner) to know how to add reportviewer in vs2019.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nuget package is from a creator other than Microsoft and may not function like the original. Here's the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017) to install the SSDT tool for VS2017 which contains Reporting Services projects. Also here's a [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2151759) to the standalone SSDT tool for VS2017.